# Slither unprotected-upgradeable-contract detector

Tags: upgrading, slither

I've been using the Openzeppelin contracts upgradeable in my project and today I decided to run the slither tool to check how is it going. Well ... apparently it isn't very good. But I can't understand where is the real problem (or if it's a false positive), so I'm in need of your help.

The detector says:

`CalculatorUpgradeable (contracts/Calculator.sol#13-59) is an upgradeable contract that does not protect its initiliaze functions: CalculatorUpgradeable.initialize() (contracts/Calculator.sol#31-33). Anyone can delete the contract with: UUPSUpgradeable.upgradeTo(address) (node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol#72-75)UUPSUpgradeable.upgradeToAndCall(address,bytes) (node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol#85-88)`

What does it mean by "does not protect its initiliaze functions"? The initialize function has the onlyOwner modifier.

On the documentation, they recommend to add a constructor to ensure "initialize" cannot be called on the logic contract. Sorry but I didn't get the idea :(

Here is the code of the contract caught by this detector:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";

contract CalculatorUpgradeable is Initializable,  OwnableUpgradeable,  UUPSUpgradeable {

    function initialize() external initializer onlyOwner {
        __Ownable_init();
    }

    function calcPercentage(uint256 amount, uint256 percentage)
        external
        pure
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return (amount * percentage * 100) / 10000;
    }

    function _authorizeUpgrade(address newImplementation)
        internal
        override
        onlyOwner
    {}
}
```

Thanks a lot for any clarification,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this it seems to be a false positive https://github.com/crytic/slither/pull/1046

It should be fixed soon.

By the way, there is an issue with your smart contract

```
function initialize() external initializer onlyOwner {
    __Ownable_init();
}
```

It should be called by `onlyOwner` but at this moment `owner` is `address(0)` and it's not possible to call function `initialize()` since you're not the owner.

Comment: Adam, Thank you for clarification about the FP and the observation about misusage of  `onlyOwner`

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the answer of contributor `0xalpharush` in this issue https://github.com/crytic/slither/issues/1136, one solution to mute this FP is adding the modifier `onlyProxy` to the initialize function.

The modifier `onlyProxy` is defined in the abstract contract `UUPSUpgradeable` and it checks that the execution of the sinalized function is being performed through a delegatecall call and that the execution context is a proxy contract with an implementation (as defined in ERC1967) pointing to implementantion contract.